# When the GRPC connection state changes?

Tags: java, connection, grpc, connectivity, grpc-java

```
    ManagedChannel managedChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost",9090).usePlaintext().build();

// Whats ConnectivityState1 here ?

    Grpc.Stub stub = Grpc.newStub(managedChannel);

// Whats ConnectivityState2 here ?

    stub.method();

// Whats ConnectivityState3 here ?
```

1. What happens ConnectivityState 1-2-3 in these stages *CONNECTING, READY, TRANSIENT_FAILURE, IDLE, SHUTDOWN*?
2. Whats the differences between `managedChannel.getState(true)` and `managedChannel.getState(false)` ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can get reference from [grpc-java](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/)

Answer (score 0):

1. ConnectivityState is the state of the underlying transport connection and not where in the code you are checking it.
2. As the [documentation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/grpc/ManagedChannel.java#L78) states, "it will try to make a connection if it is  currently IDLE" i.e. there are no active or pending RPCs.